# RMagick Paperclip image attachment to S3 on Heroku

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, paperclip, rmagick

On Heroku, I have an image file I have manipulated with RMagick in Rails.  Now I want to send it to S3 with Paperclip.

I have a model, User, which ":has_attached_file" as required.  Then, a User instance in my controller @user.

Now, I have an image in RMagick like:

```
new_image = old_image.composite(other_img, 76, 11, Magick::AtopCompositeOp)
```

... which is at the end of a long chain of RMagick manipulations.  Logically, I would simply do:

@user.update_attribute(:image, new_image)

But this does not work, and I get "Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError" ... and it references some static file in /assets/images which was last accessed earlier in the RMagick process.

This question has been asked before, but not answered.  For example, [RMagick mask Paperclip image attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365984/rmagick-mask-paperclip-image-attachment)
That example is Exactly what I want to do, but he gave up and did it another way (which will not work for me).

I have also seen the solutions where one writes a Tempfile first, like here:
[Create paperclip attachment from rmagick image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035212/create-paperclip-attachment-from-rmagick-image)

Heroku docs here:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem
... shows how to save a tmp file on Heroku, but those are gone, even within a single process, when Heroku restarts your dyno at some random time.

I have read that Paperclip **uses rmagick in the background** to do its own processing, so there must be a direct-way to solve this.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your comment sooner.  No.  I am stuck using the tmp file method.  In my testing, it has not wiped out the file before it was used.